# Why does the drop shadow in my 9 patch look bad?

Tags: android, nine-patch

Instead of fading from dark grey to white, there's an odd gray border around the shadow/whole image when using my 9patch. Is there some sort of limitation to graphics?

I created a simple 100x100 image, with a rounded rectangle and a drop shadow / stroke in photoshop. Then, I used the 9Patch tool and just selected 1 px from each side.

On the Emulator, it looks okay. I can't tell if it's there or if it's the screen. On a Cisco Cius, it is very visible. It seems as if there is a drop shadow, but lining around the entire image is a gray border 'behind' the 9 patch. It's much fainter on the screen (the picture below doesn't show it well). Is it a limitation of the hardware perhaps?

[image: Ex]

[image: 9 Patch]

Comment: It'd help if you could include a screenshot

Comment: Do you have ADB set up and working with your Cisco device? If so you should be able to pull screen shots from it that way. It may also be helpful if you can just post your actual 9 patch image file.

Comment: @DoctorOreo even after your edit there is still no screen shot

Comment: I'm working on getting an actual screenshot, I posted a poor photo, but it gets the picture across...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding RGBA_8888 to the top of your activity. Your image contains a gradient and in my experience setting the format to the above fixes it. the good new is RGBA_8888 will be the default starting in ICS for all devices.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(Res.layout.toplayer);
}
```

Comment: Yep. I saw this elsewhere a few minutes ago, and this seemed to work and also fixed the banding in the gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, Android builds can get into a state where all the nine-patches look awful. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding.